# Console2 - open new tab in existing session from cmd

Tags: windows-7, command-line, console2

Is it possible to open a new Console2 tab from cmd?

I run specific commands from my text editor (sublime) and would love to open them in console instead of regular cmds.

However, I am only able to open a whole new instance of Console2, which I don't like.

Is it possible to target an instance of Console2?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Sorry for self-promotion. I'm the author of another [Console Emulator](http://code.google.com/p/conemu-maximus5/). One of its features - is opening new tab from existing tab (from any program or batch file). Just type

```
"%ConEmuBaseDir%\ConEmuC.exe" /c program.exe <arguments> -new_console
```

arguments - (optional) switches of program.exe. [-new_console](http://code.google.com/p/conemu-maximus5/wiki/NewConsole) switch has several options.

```
-new_console[:abch[N]ru[:user:pwd]]
 a - RunAs shell verb (as Admin on Vista+, login/passw in Win2k and WinXP)
 b - Create background tab
 c - force enable 'Press Enter or Esc to close console' (default)
 h<height> - i.e., h0 - turn buffer off, h9999 - switch to 9999 lines
 n - disable 'Press Enter or Esc to close console'
 r - run as restricted user
 u - ConEmu choose user dialog
 u:<user>:<pwd> - specify user/pwd in args, MUST BE LAST OPTION
```

BTW, you may start same way GUI programs in ConEmu tab, or start console tools from GUI applications (started in tab).

Attach of existing console or GUI app is also available.

Comment: see http://superuser.com/questions/495520/duplicate-session-in-conemu as well

Comment: On a related note, I wasn't able to figure out how to save my session so that when I reopen ConEmu it opens up to all the same tabs AND the same directories for each tab.