# Duplicate session in ConEmu

Tags: windows, console, conemu

Is there way to "duplicate" session in ConEmu.

I know it's not possible for every kind of terminal (cmd.exe, powershell, etc),
but I'm most interested in following situation:

- I'm in cmd.exe console inside ConEmu.
- By typing Ctrl-T (the shortcut I specified) I am able to open a new console tab, with a new session (cmd.exe).

I want **this session to start in the same directory as the first one**, original one. I'm *feeling* that it can be done with %cd% variable or similar, but I couldn't manage it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Variant 1**

Type in **existing** cmd prompt

```
cmd -new_console
```

and press Enter. Also you may create hotkey/macro for this sequence, for example <kbd>Apps</kbd><kbd>N</kbd> -->

```
print("cmd -new_console\n")
```

or create cmd-file or doskey alias.

---

**Variant 2**

Use menu item `Duplicate root...`. It will make a copy of your most parent (root) shell of the current tab (where you are calling menu item). Also you may disable duplicate confirmation in the `Settings` \ `Confirmation`.

---

**Variant 3**

With latest versions (from 140818) you also may use `%CD%` environment variable within `Shell()` [GuiMacro](https://code.google.com/p/conemu-maximus5/wiki/GuiMacro) function. How to set up your shell described [here](https://code.google.com/p/conemu-maximus5/wiki/ShellWorkDir).

```
Shell("", "cmd", "", "%CD%")
```

Comment: Thanks.

It's not perfect solution, because it doesn't work if I'm in a middle of some application (ssh, vagrant, anything that can be waited for long).

But, it's a solution. And thanks again.

Comment: If you are in a middle ssh (or smth other) - "duplicate session" will be ambiguous. Because "what to duplicate"? You active session is ssh, not cmd. Yes, cmd may be at the bottom of the process stack, but what is it state? Undetermined I guess...

Comment: You're right.

But still, very often I need exactly that:
to duplicate the last state of the bottom of the process stack.

Comment: Well, check 121109. "Duplicate root" in Tab menu. Works with cmd.

Answer (score 2):

The following will do the same thing for PowerShell

```
ConEmu64.exe /config "shell" /dir "$(pwd)" /cmd powershell -new_console:n
```

I created the following function that is loaded in my PowerShell profile

```
function Create-Console($path = $(pwd)) {
  $console = Resolve-Path (join-path (join-path "$env:PROGRAMW6432*" "console*") "ConEmu64*");
  . $console /config "shell" /dir "$path" /cmd powershell -new_console:n
}

Set-Alias sh Create-Console
```

Then I can execute the following in the console to create a new PowerShell tab in the same directory:

```
> sh
```

or create a tab in a different directory with:

```
> sh c:\some\directory\path
```