# Duplicate Git Bash tab in ConEmu through command/script

Tags: terminal, conemu

I'm trying to figure out how to duplicate my **git bash** tab in ConEmu via a command typed into the console and nothing seems to be working.

Followed along with this: [Duplicate session in ConEmu](https://superuser.com/questions/495520/duplicate-session-in-conemu)

but..

```
bash -new_console
```

just throws

```
bash: -w: invalid option
```

Maybe bash isn't what I'm looking for? My default Task is **{Bash::Git bash}**

Does anyone know the best way to create a shortcut that can be typed into the console, or ran via an sh script, that will open a new tab **in the same directory** as the tab it was typed into?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just prepend your command with `ConEmuC -c`. Example:

```
ConEmuC -c bash -new_console --login -i
```

Cygwin and msys due to hardcoded forking technology doesn't pass command line to their processes using standard Windows API.

Comment: That helped a lot! Although it appears doing something like `ConEmuC -c bash -new_console --login -i && gulp watch` or `ConEmuC -c bash -new_console --login -i && git status` doesn't work. Is there a workaround for this that allows executing a script in the new tab?