# Open new tab with current directory with Console 2

Tags: console2

Can I open a new tab with current tab's current directory in Console 2?

I found this question, but the solution using `ConEmu` not `Console 2`.
[Console2 - open new tab in existing session from cmd](https://superuser.com/questions/420444/console2-open-new-tab-in-existing-session-from-cmd)

I'm using `nyaos` as a shell for `Console 2`.

Does anyone know how to do it?

Comment: Why not to try ConEmu?

Comment: Because in my environment ConEmu behaves often strangely. Sometimes when I put `Ctrl + a`, it takes several seconds til the cursor move to line head and give me a lot of beep sounds. And I can't say when these problem happens.

Comment: Really strange. ConEmu does not "process" `Ctrl+A`. It is shell responsibility. Nyaos, yeah? Interesting to see screenshot. Also, ConEmu does not "beep" at all, beeps can be produced by console applications only.

Comment: Oh, really!? Sorry I didn't know about that I can not yet distinguish what is terminal's task and what is shell's task. I'll consider to use another shell. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

`<path_to_console>/Console.exe -t <tab_type> -reuse -r "-c '<your_command> ; bash --login -i'"`

I add `bash --login -i` at the end to avoid the shell closing after my command has run.